# Add new worksheet(s) to existing pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

*Please note:* I will post here, according to the suggestions from [Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/which-stack-exchange-site-is-best-for-microsoft-excel-questions)

On a dedicated worksheet, I have a pivot table summarizing data from another worksheet in the same workbook.

Now, for the sake of readability, I have created another in the same workbook another worksheet with new data (keeping the same data structure as the previous worksheet)

How could I aggregate both the worksheets (old and new) in the existing pivot? How can I update it? Is there any way to accomplish the such task from GUI, instead of scripting?

Here there is a very simplified example, according to ***Frédéric Loyer*** request:

a) a sheet with a customers' backup report of March

[image: asheet]

b) a summary pivot of occurrences

[image: apivot]

I would like to add data of April, to the existing pivot summary, next time I will create a new worksheet for that month*

*: I don't know a priori how many sheets I will have to create for how many months

P.S.: I need to keep separated data per month in different sheets

Comment: You should provide a precise example of what you want to do. Aggregating two tables can be understood in multiple ways. The format of the unpivoted data can be useful. It may be easier to aggregate data which are not pivoted.

Answer (score 0):

For all the data sheets, create a table (Insert Table) and gives them all a meaningful name.

Then in each table, Data/From a table, close and load… (the drop-down menu) and ask to create simply a connection.

Then Data/new query/other sources/empty request.

In the advanced editor, type

```ocaml
let
  Source = Table.Combine( { Tab1,Tab2 } ),
  Select = Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"CUSTOMER", "STATUS"}),
  Pivot = Table.Pivot(Select, List.Distinct(Select[STATUS]), "STATUS", "STATUS", List.Count)
in
  Pivot
```

The second line (`Source=`) should indicates all the tables you have declared. (Then meaningful and consistent names are useful). Validate the query. Verify if you have your pivot. Now click on Close and load icon. This will create the pivot table in a tab.

If you want to add a new dataset. Declare it like a tab with a name you want, create the connection. Go to the pivot, Request/modify request/advanced editor, change the `Source=` line to add the name you have typed. Validate, Close and load.

The script is picky with the case of your column names.

Would will need Excel2016 or more recent.